# How to convert =MATCH(VALUE(A1), VALUE(B:B), 0) into vba code

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a way to do =MATCH(VALUE(A1), VALUE(B:B), 0) in vba in excel.

I have two columns that I am matching, both might be interger or string types. I know how I would do this but it involves many if statements. I was wondering if there is an elegant way to do this.

Comment: `Dim res: res = mySheet.Evaluate("MATCH(VALUE(A1), VALUE(B:B), 0)")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a WorksheetFunction.Match method...example below (commented for explanation):

```
Sub test()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lookuprng As Range
    Dim res

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1")
    Set lookuprng = ws.Range("B:B")

    On Error Resume Next

    res = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(rng.Value, lookuprng, 0) 'will return a row number
    If Err.Number > 0 Then  'the above command will throw an error if there is no match
        MsgBox "No Match!", vbCritical
        Err.Clear
    Else
        'do something with the matched row
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I accepted this answer, but I was more interested in the VALUE() portion of the code. I had it matching but the values made the match miss if one column was an integer and the other was a string. I will probably just use Tim's response.

Answer (score 0):

`Evaluate()` have a limit, max 255 Characters only, if your formula too lengthy will have an error.

I recommend to use `Application.Match()`, rather `Application.WorksheetFunctions.Match()`.

Both method are Identical, except the respond, when there have no Macthed value.

You can use `IsError(Application.Match())` to check if value able to match, without the need of Error Handler. **Return True if not able to match.**

Using `Application.WorksheetFunctions.Match()` will need Error Handler.